# Having trouble with borders and inline tags

Tags: html, css

I was trying to make a `<p>` tag with a border on the bottom in the middle of an image. But I came across some problems. For starters, I added the `display: inline` attribute so the border would appear only under the text, but then I wasn't able to text align, so my first idea was to add margins and manually edit out the borders, but when I change  the zoom level or switch to mobile view the problem borders appeared again.

Here is  my code if anyone can find a way to to text-align with `display:block;` or any other solution to my problem.

```css
p#p01 {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  border-bottom: solid black;
}

div#div03 {
  background-image: url("background.jpg");
  width: 1000px;
  height: 300px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 1000px 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div03">
  <p id="p01">TESTE TETSTEE</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change `width: 1000px` to `width:100%` for `div#div03`

```css
p#p01 {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  border-bottom: solid black;
}

div#div03 {
  background-image: url("background.jpg");
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 1000px 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div03">
  <p id="p01">TESTE TETSTEE</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes but then the text  would be on the center of the screen rather than the image [Here](http://prntscr.com/sd8nd0) and [Here](http://prntscr.com/sd8nyv) is what i mean.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the thickness of your border. Otherwise, it won't appear.

```
p#p01 {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

Happy coding!